# Difference between two question formats?

Tags: grammar, differences, slang, questions, do-support

I have seen people using following two formats to form a question:

> 1) Why *do* people lie?
>   2) Why people lie?

The difference is, in the first one, there is an explicit use of **do** whereas the second question omits *do*.

Would you kindly explain the differences between these two question forms.

Comment: 2) isn't a question.

Comment: could you please elaborate on your answer.

Comment: This question would be more appropriate on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). Here, it's General Reference.

Comment: I'll try. It will take some time though.

Comment: @Flair You say you have seen people use the second format to form a question, please can you tell us where/when you saw this and (ideally) provide a link to such usage.

Comment: I agree with the other comments that the second form is not a valid question form. But, with the question mark (‘?’) removed, it can be used as a _title_ or other descriptor for an _answer_ to the question posed in form #1. For example, it’s easy to imagine a web page or magazine article titled “Why People Lie”.

Comment: The 2nd example, though it starts with an interrogative (why) is not a question, grammatically.  It is a statement that can be restated as, "The reason people lie."  In the *statement* "Why people lie", ***"why"*** is being used as a substitute for "The reason" - a common usage to my US Midwestern ears an eyes.

Answer (score 2):

The second one is not proper English, but is commonly seen in [*African American Vernacular English*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_American_Vernacular_English#Other_grammatical_characteristics), which is an English dialect that has roots in the [*South American English*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_American_English) dialect.

Answer (score 1):

The number 2 is not grammatically correct if it's a question. The question formation is:

- **QUESTION WORD + AUXILIARY + PRONOUN + VERB + REST** (Example: *Why did you eat the last piece of cake?*)
- **WHO + VERB + REST** (Example: *Who is the monarch of Swaziland?*) *OR* **WHO + AUXILIARY + PRONOUN + VERB + REST** (Example: *Who did you meet yesterday night?*)
- **AUXILIARY + PRONOUN + VERB + REST** (Example: *Does he think that you're right?*)

[English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) is a more appropriate place to ask this type of question.